# the output is not in correct order

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

i have a code in python2.7 which gets a line of text as its list elements and returns it as json. here is the code:

```
import itertools

lines=["Hamlet"
   ,"William Shakespeare",
   "Edited Barbara B Mowat Paul Werstine"
   ,"Michael Poston Rebecca Niles"]
LinesMap=dict()
for line in lines:
    list=[l for l in line.split(' ')]
    d = dict(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(list)] * 2, fillvalue=None))
    LinesMap.update(d)

print(LinesMap)
```

the output is:

```
{'William': 'Shakespeare', 'Edited': 'Barbara', 'B': 'Mowat',    

'Michael':'Poston', 'Paul': 'Werstine', 'Rebecca': 'Niles', 'Hamlet': None}
```

whereas it should be:

```
{'Hamlet': None, 'William': 'Shakespeare', 'Edited': 'Barbara', 

'B':'Mowat', 'Paul': 'Werstine', 'Michael': 'Poston', 'Rebecca': 'Niles'}
```

if i make the list longer it will be even worse! why this is not in correct order? but when i run the same code in python3.6,with python3 syntax of course, the order is correct. the python3.6 code is:

```
import itertools

lines=["Hamlet"
   ,"William Shakespeare",
   "Edited Barbara B Mowat Paul Werstine"
   ,"Michael Poston Rebecca Niles"]
LinesMap=dict()
for line in lines:
   list=[l for l in line.split(' ')]
   d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(list)] * 2, fillvalue=None))
   LinesMap = {**LinesMap, **d}

print(LinesMap)
```

this is one problem. the other one is that for short lists it's ok and runs properly. but when the list is longer and has too many elements, the output does not show anything and it seems to be broken. this is in windows and in linux it doesn't break. what is the problem?

ps: i have to run it in python 2.7 for some reasons!

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered before Python 3.6 - which means that you can't rely on any particular order in earlier versions.

Comment: you might want to try `from collections import OrderedDict` if you are limited to 2.7

Comment: Also add a space in "Hamlet " so that the "None" entry will be added.

Comment: It looks like you want them in input order.  Try  `from Collections import OrderedDict` and use that instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 4):

The Python `dict` object has no intrinsic order except in quite recent versions of Python, so you can't assume you'll get objects out in the same order you put them in.

If you need that functionality, there is an `OrderedDict` object you can use.

```
import random
from collections import OrderedDict

# Normal dict behavior:
numbers = {}
random_nums = (random.random() for _ in range(1000))
for i in random_nums:
    numbers[i] = random.random()
assert list(numbers.keys()) != list(random_nums)

# Ordered dict behavior:
numbers = OrderedDict()
for i in random_nums:
    numbers[i] = random.random()
assert list(numbers.keys()) == list(random_nums)
```

Comment: yes although your `assert` doesn't prove anything, regular `dict` passes this assertion in Python 2 also (EDIT: because integers mostly hash to themselves- answers your question below)

Comment: There we go, using random numbers instead

Comment: Demonstrating a data structure is *guaranteed* ordered just isn't possible from a few examples, instead you should just link to the docs or language spec

Comment: i used OrderedDict instead of dict and the output was:                            OrderedDict([('Hamlet', None), ('William', 'Shakespeare'), ('Edited', 'Barbara'), ('B', 'Mowat'), ('Paul', 'Werstine'), ('Michael', 'Poston'), ('Rebecca', 'Niles')])             so the order is correct. but how can i get the desired output which is in this format:                                                                                                          {'Hamlet': None, 'William': 'Shakespeare', 'Edited': 'Barbara', 
'B':'Mowat', 'Paul': 'Werstine', 'Michael': 'Poston', 'Rebecca': 'Niles'}

Comment: Why do you want it to be formatted that way? That formatting conveys that the object represented is a plain old Dict, which an OrderedDict isn't.

Comment: You could always hack that output together of course: ```>>> output = '{'
>>> for key, value in d.iteritems():
...   output += "{}: {}, ".format(repr(key), repr(value))
... 
>>> output = output.strip()
>>> output += '}'
>>> print(output)
```